# Return another data if searched data not available Rails search form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi In my rails application I have a calendar and a search form I have already loaded a Image for the year of 2014 each and every day .Now if I click on any day the corresponding image come . What I want is if I click on some date on 2015 application has to retrieve 2014 data on the same day and month.This is my the codes all I have done

-- search field --

```
 <div id="search_field" >
    <%= search_form_for @search,  :id => "search_form"  do |f| %>
     <div id="field">
       <%= f.text_field :date_cont , :id  => 'search_box' %>
     </div>
   <%= f.submit %>
 <% end %>
```

-- result field -

```
<div id="image">
  <%= render partial: 'image', format: 'js' %>
```

I have created a partial image with this code

```
 <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <td><%= image_tag post.name %></td>
```

and my controller is

```
def index   
 if params[:q]
   @search=Post.search(params[:q])
  @posts = @search.result
else
  @posts=Post.where(date: Date.today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) 
end
```

I have done some things but it not workout . What I will do?

Comment: It's very important for you to understand that you are involved in your project for a long time you know every piece of it but we don't. We only can make wild guesses so therefore please post more code and explain your problem at the current state no one will be able to help you. also checkout [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yeah sorry buddy, Now I have clearly shown what I have done, will repeat the same thing next time I ask questions

Answer (score 0):

I think u r using ransack gem so probably u have specified the gem 'ransack' in ur gem file
In search_field_form line specify
url: search_controllername_path, method: :post
try this one, it may help or look in this tutorial
http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack